# What is CPUQuota PerSec and PerPeriod in systemd?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, systemd, systemctl, clamav

The manpage for `systemd.resource-control` says nothing about `CPUQuotaPerSecUSec` and little about `CPUQuotaPeriodUSec`.

It says nothing either about being set with the value 'infinity', as it is in the `clamav*` systemd services, as you can see:

```
._. systemctl show clamav* | grep CPUQuota
CPUQuotaPerSecUSec=infinity
CPUQuotaPeriodUSec=infinity
CPUQuotaPerSecUSec=infinity
CPUQuotaPeriodUSec=infinity
```

What it does say is that `CPUQuotaPeriodSec=` sets the duration over which `CPUQuota=` time is measured.

But what difference would it make if it was set to `1ms` or `100ms` or `1000ms`? What does value `infinity` do? And what difference does it make if `CPUQuota` is not set, as appears to be the case with the `clamav*` services?